# JavaFX xattr-win error when showing FileChooser

Tags: java, javafx, javafx-8, filechooser

I'm developping a desktop JavaFX8 (v8.0.92-b14) application.

Somewhere in my app, there is a *File > Open/Save/Save As* option, which opens a FileChooser dialog. Everything is fine before opening it (using `fileChooser.showSaveDialog(stg);` and `fileChooser.showOpenDialog(stg);`).

However, when I do, this print out in the console (in red):

```
xattr-win[1463778050]:Could not get ADS for  E:\ : Could not stat.
xattr-win[1463778050]:Could not get ADS for  E:\ : Could not stat.
xattr-win[1463778050]:Could not get ADS for  E:\ : Could not stat.
xattr-win[1463778050]:Could not get ADS for  E:\ : Could not stat.
xattr-win[1463778050]:Could not get ADS for  E:\ : Could not stat.
```

And that's not a mistake, it does print it 5 times. The application doesn't stop, and I can still choose my file, but I want to know why this happens, and get rid of it if it's possible.

In windows, **E:/** is an empty DVD RW drive.

Thanks!

Comment: Ist this the Swing JFileChooser? If it is, your problem  is probably, that you are creating it in a JFX Thread...

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NTFS#Alternate_data_streams_.28ADS.29 Maybe this helps...

Comment: It's a full JavaFX application, so I use a `javafx.stage.FileChooser`.

Comment: I think the Problem is, that your FileChooser thinks, that E:\ is a valid rewritable HDD

Comment: It seems, that this is a JavaFX Error I don't think there's an easy way resolving it...